# In symfony, how to change the value of the variable in .env file?

Tags: php, symfony

In symfony, I am writing bash script for deployment. For that, I want to change variable's value in .env file from bash script. My `.env` file has variable as:
`APP_DISABLED=true`.

In bash script I want to change it as `APP_DISABLED=false`.

I don't know how can I edit `.env` file and update the value from bash script.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your bash script:

```
sed -i "s/^APP_DISABLED=true/APP_DISABLED=false/" /path/to/.env/file
```